# How to draw curve by InDesign/Illustrator path points?

Tags: c++, delphi, adobe-indesign, adobe-illustrator, bezier

The following numbers are the path points of a very simple curve from *Adobe InDesign*:

```
pathPoint0 = app.selection[0].paths[0].pathPoints[0]  // PointType: SMOOTH
pathPoint1 = app.selection[0].paths[0].pathPoints[1]  // PointType: PLAIN

pathPoint0.leftDirection : {x=87.32570997045623, y=30.81406367905744}   
pathPoint0.anchor : {x=67.69218412206757, y=134.53280706833522}  
pathPoint0.rightDirection : {x=48.0586582736789, y=238.25155045761298}  

pathPoint1.anchor : {117.05865827421783, 143.2515504576449}
```

The curve contains 2 path points, an smooth point and a plain point.

InDesign simple curve:
[image]
<sub>(source: [no-ip.org](http://doxy.no-ip.org/idcurve.png))</sub>

I am trying to draw this curve by this code:

```
MoveToEx(hDC, 67, 134, NULL);  
POINT points[] = {{87, 30}, {48, 238}, {117, 143}};  
PolyBezierTo(hDC, points, 3);
```

But I can not draw same curve, my drawn curve is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [no-ip.org](http://doxy.no-ip.org/mycurve.png))</sub>

Where is my mistake? Is any conversion need?
Thanks.

Comment: @mhtaqia: I suspect he's commenting on the low resolution and (especially) lack of anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm...

```
MoveToEx(hDC, 67, 134, NULL);  
POINT points[] = {{87, 30}, {48, 238}, {117, 143}};
```

Your first point is 67,134 your second is 87,30 and your third 48,238.

With Y values of 134 then 30 then 238, I'd expect about what you seem to be getting -- a line that goes one direction, then sharply back in about the opposite direction.

The first point you're getting from InDesign is a "direction" point -- but for PolyBezier, the first and last points are the anchors. I'm not absolutely certain, but I think what you want is to rearrange the points so your anchors come first and last, and InDesign's "direction" points are used as the two control points in between:

```
POINT points[] = {{87, 30}, {67, 134}, {48,238}, {117, 143}};   
//                 anchor,   control,   control,  anchor
PolyBezier(hDC, points, 4);
```

Unless you're using MoveTo/LineTo (and such) otherwise, I'd just PolyBezier instead of PolyBezierTo -- keeps all the data in one place.

Comment: I tried: POINT points[] = {{67, 134}, {87, 30}, {48, 238}, {117, 143}}; PolyBezier(hDC, points, 4); the result was same, note: the second and third poins are "control points".

Comment: @mhtaqia: Yes, I'm pretty sure you want to swap your first and second points, as shown in my answer.

Comment: The curve drawn by your code is http://doxy.no-ip.org/jerry-curve.png It does not seems to be the InDesign curve.